# MySQL master-slave replication not updating

Tags: mysql, mariadb, database-replication

I set up MASTER->SLAVE database replication. Looks like everything fine, but when I change the master, the slave database is not updated. Exec_Master_Log_Pos on slave is updated when I update master db. I am enable logging on slave

```
log_output              = "FILE"
general_log_file        = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
general_log             = 1
```

In the slave log only these records appear when I apply any changes to the master database:

```
220129 23:10:33      5 Query    BEGIN
                     5 Query    COMMIT /* implicit, from Xid_log_event */
```

**master**

5.7.36-0ubuntu0.18.04.1-log

**slave**

10.6.4-MariaDB-1:10.6.4+maria~focal-log

On the master the base is called alpha, on the slave - beta

**master my.cfg**

```
server-id = 1
log-bin = /mnt/sdb/var/lib/mysql/mysql-bin
binlog_do_db = alpha
```

**slave my.cfg**

```
server-id = 3
replicate-do-db     = beta
```

**master**

```
mysql> SHOW MASTER STATUS\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
             File: mysql-bin.000006
         Position: 24181
     Binlog_Do_DB: alpha
 Binlog_Ignore_DB:
Executed_Gtid_Set:
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

**slave**

```
MariaDB [(none)]> SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
                Slave_IO_State: Waiting for master to send event
                   Master_Host: 144.217.157.211
                   Master_User: beta_user
                   Master_Port: 3306
                 Connect_Retry: 60
               Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000006
           Read_Master_Log_Pos: 24181
                Relay_Log_File: mysqld-relay-bin.000010
                 Relay_Log_Pos: 5097
         Relay_Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000006
              Slave_IO_Running: Yes
             Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
               Replicate_Do_DB: beta
           Replicate_Ignore_DB:
            Replicate_Do_Table:
        Replicate_Ignore_Table:
       Replicate_Wild_Do_Table:
   Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table:
                    Last_Errno: 0
                    Last_Error:
                  Skip_Counter: 0
           Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 24181
               Relay_Log_Space: 5407
               Until_Condition: None
                Until_Log_File:
                 Until_Log_Pos: 0
            Master_SSL_Allowed: No
            Master_SSL_CA_File:
            Master_SSL_CA_Path:
               Master_SSL_Cert:
             Master_SSL_Cipher:
                Master_SSL_Key:
         Seconds_Behind_Master: 0
 Master_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert: No
                 Last_IO_Errno: 0
                 Last_IO_Error:
                Last_SQL_Errno: 0
                Last_SQL_Error:
   Replicate_Ignore_Server_Ids:
              Master_Server_Id: 1
                Master_SSL_Crl:
            Master_SSL_Crlpath:
                    Using_Gtid: No
                   Gtid_IO_Pos:
       Replicate_Do_Domain_Ids:
   Replicate_Ignore_Domain_Ids:
                 Parallel_Mode: optimistic
                     SQL_Delay: 0
           SQL_Remaining_Delay: NULL
       Slave_SQL_Running_State: Slave has read all relay log; waiting for more updates
              Slave_DDL_Groups: 0
Slave_Non_Transactional_Groups: 0
    Slave_Transactional_Groups: 0
1 row in set (0.001 sec)
```

The binary log on the master is written after each change of the base. The slave also gets change notifications, but why doesn't the slave base get updated? I have tried this scheme on several servers and the result is always the same.

Comment: why not use the same database version and type, but i think in dba is a better place for your question

Comment: If `binlog_do_db = alpha`  this  `replicate-do-db = beta` should be `replicate-do-db = alpha`

Comment: No. ```replicate-do-db``` - this is db name on slave. If change this to alpha, then error - ```Error executing row event: 'Table 'alpha.stat' doesn't exist'```

Comment: `replicate-do-db makes the slave  read statements from the relay log, that are for the specified DB` . You are making logs binlog_do_db  for `alpha`  database on the Master, and you are reading for the `beta` database on slave.